# Upload Múltiplo com problemas

Tags: php

Tenho esse código que deveria fazer um upload múltiplo de imagens, mas ele só realiza o upload da primeira imagem. Alguém pode me ajudar.

**PHP**

```
 require('public/plugin/resize2/resize2.php');

 if (is_dir('/var/www/sistema/uploads/trn/'.app::$key.'/')) {

 } else {
     mkdir('/var/www/sistema/uploads/trn/'.app::$key.'/', 0777, true);
 }


 $arquivos = array($_FILES['foto_treinamento']['name']);

 foreach($arquivos as $key = > $reg) {

     $_UP['pasta'] = '/var/www/sistema/uploads/trn/'.app::$key.'/';

     $_UP['tamanho'] = 5000 * 5000 * 2;

     $_UP['extensoes'] = array('jpg', 'png');

     $_UP['renomeia'] = true;

     $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
     $_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do PHP';
     $_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especifiado no HTML';
     $_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
     $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

     if ($_FILES['foto_treinamento']['error'][$key] != 0) {
         die("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:".$_UP['erros'][$_FILES['foto_treinamento']['error'][$key]]);
         exit;
     }

     $nome_arquivo = explode(".", $_FILES['foto_treinamento']['name'][$key]);
     $extensao = strtolower(end($nome_arquivo));
     if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
         return "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript' TYPE='text/javascript'>
                                            alert('Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png.');
                                            history.back();
                                        </SCRIPT>";
     }

     if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {

         $nome_final = md5(time()).'.'.$extensao;
     } else {

         $nome_final = $_FILES['foto_treinamento']['name'];
     }


     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto_treinamento']['tmp_name'][$key], $_UP['pasta'].$nome_final)) {

     }

     $resizeObj = new resize('/var/www/sistema/uploads/trn/'.app::$key.'/'.$nome_final);

     $resizeObj - > resizeImage(800, 600, 'crop');

     $resizeObj - > saveImage('/var/www/sistema/uploads/trn/'.app::$key.'/', 100);

     connection::exec("insert into trn_fotos (trn_id,foto_trn)values(".app::$key.",'".$nome_final."')");
 }

 header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="#ACTION_FOTOS#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
id="formulario">
    <label>
        Upload de fotos
        <input name="foto_treinamento[]" type="file" multiple />
    </label>
    <hr>
    <div class="button-group expanded float-center">
        <button class="success button fi-check" type="submit">
            Enviar fotos
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**var_dump($arquivos);**

> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "1.png" [1]=> string(5)
>   "2.png" [2]=> string(5) "3.png" } }